# Copying a worksheet between workbooks using cells as guidance on what to copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following in Call.xlsm, A2 contains the path to a second Workbook, Data.xlsm. A3 holds the sheetname I'm trying to copy from Data.xlsm to Call.xlsm.

[image]

I understand the first step to copying a sheet from another workbook, is to open it the other workbook (this is in Call.xlsm):

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim filenameIS As String
    filenameIS = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2")
    Workbooks.Open (filenameIS)
    
    Workbooks(filenameis).WorkSheets("Data 2018").CopyBefore:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))

End Sub
```

This returns:

> Compile error: Synatax error

It doesn't like the :=

Comment: Worked it out, it was the speech marks but straggling on how to do the copying given the macro is in Call.xlsm

Comment: A2 value should not have any quotes

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, yeah that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub GetData()
    Dim filenameIS As String, wb As Workbook, wsInfo As Worksheet
    
    Set wsInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    filenameIS = wsInfo.Range("a2")
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filenameIS) 'get a reference to the opened workbook
    'Copy the worksheet named in A3 over to `wb`
    wb.Worksheets(wsInfo.Range("A3").Value).Copy _
         Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work, it returns a ```Run-time error 9 subscript out of range``` and selects the two bottom lines. To be clear, the places in which the sheet should be copied doesn't matter too much but at the start of Call.xlsm would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry had the copy the wrong way around...

Answer (score 0):

### Import Sheet From Closed Workbook

```vb
Sub ImportSheet()
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = CStr(dws.Range("A2").Value)
    Dim sSheetName As String: sSheetName = CStr(dws.Range("A3").Value)
    
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    IsFound = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(sFilePath)
    
    If Not IsFound Then
        MsgBox "The file '" & sFilePath & "' doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
     
    Dim sws As Object ' if it's a worksheet, use 'Dim sws As Worksheet'
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = swb.Sheets(sSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not sws Is Nothing Then sws.Copy Before:=dwb.Sheets(1)
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & sSheetName & "' doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & sSheetName & "' imported.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```